# Why cant i filter a python index using a defined list?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

So im taking a pandas and Numpy course and ran into a problem, the course instructor performed the solution  and it worked, i followed every step and it didnt work for me

Pardon the length, i included the actual datasets for clarity

i assigned the following items in a list to the variable " dates" as instructed, see below

```
dates = [
    "2016-12-22",
    "2017-05-03",
    "2017-01-06",
    "2017-03-05",
    "2017-02-12",
    "2017-03-21",
    "2017-04-14",
    "2017-04-15",
]
```

then i have a series im working against named oil_series with the following data

```
Date is the Index Name

date

2016-12-20
2016-12-21
2016-12-22
2016-12-23
2016-12-27
2016-12-28
2016-12-29
2016-12-30
2017-01-03
2017-01-04
2017-01-05
2017-01-06
2017-01-09
2017-01-10
2017-01-11
2017-01-12
2017-01-13
2017-01-17
2017-01-18
2017-01-19
2017-01-20
2017-01-23
2017-01-24
2017-01-25
2017-01-26
2017-01-27
2017-01-30
2017-01-31
2017-02-01
2017-02-02
2017-02-03
2017-02-06
2017-02-07
2017-02-08
2017-02-09
2017-02-10
2017-02-13
2017-02-14
2017-02-15
2017-02-16
2017-02-17
2017-02-21
2017-02-22
2017-02-23
2017-02-24
2017-02-27
2017-02-28
2017-03-01
2017-03-02
2017-03-03
2017-03-06
2017-03-07
2017-03-08
2017-03-09
2017-03-10
2017-03-13
2017-03-14
2017-03-15
2017-03-16
2017-03-17
2017-03-20
2017-03-21
2017-03-22
2017-03-23
2017-03-24
2017-03-27
2017-03-28
2017-03-29
2017-03-30
2017-03-31
2017-04-03
2017-04-04
2017-04-05
2017-04-06
2017-04-07
2017-04-10
2017-04-11
2017-04-12
2017-04-13
2017-04-17
2017-04-18
2017-04-19
2017-04-20
2017-04-21
2017-04-24
2017-04-25
2017-04-26
2017-04-27
2017-04-28
2017-05-01
2017-05-02
2017-05-03
2017-05-04
2017-05-05
2017-05-08
2017-05-09
2017-05-10
2017-05-11
2017-05-12
2017-05-15

Values

52.22
51.44
51.98
52.01
52.82
54.01
53.8
53.75
52.36
53.26
53.77
53.98
51.95
50.82
52.19
53.01
52.36
52.45
51.12
51.39
52.33
52.77
52.38
52.14
53.24
53.18
52.63
52.75
53.9
53.55
53.81
53.01
52.19
52.37
52.99
53.84
52.96
53.21
53.11
53.41
53.41
54.02
53.61
54.48
53.99
54.04
54
53.82
52.63
53.33
53.19
52.68
49.83
48.75
48.05
47.95
47.24
48.34
48.3
48.34
47.79
47.02
47.29
47
47.3
47.02
48.36
49.47
50.3
50.54
50.25
50.99
51.14
51.69
52.25
53.06
53.38
53.12
53.19
52.62
52.46
50.49
50.26
49.64
48.9
49.22
49.22
48.96
49.31
48.83
47.65
47.79
45.55
46.23
46.46
45.84
47.28
47.81
47.83
48.86
```

So when i write the following code to filter the "oil_prices" whose index are dates against the "dates" list i created, see code below

```
mask = (oil_series.index.isin(dates)) & (oil_series <= 50)

oil_series.loc[mask]
```

the following error occurs

[Error from running the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZpWP.png)

Please help me understand the problem

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why do you want to index the date? be a separate column and filter it.

Comment: What is the output of `print(sr.index[:2])`?

Comment: @Corralien

MultiIndex([('2016-12-20',),
            ('2016-12-21',)],
           names=['date'])

Comment: @tornikekharitonishvili its part of the training, dealing with scenarios

Comment: @YimbanjiMutambo. Can you check my answer, please? It seems you have a MultiIndex of only one level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your comment, you have a `MultiIndex` of only one level. Convert it to `Index` and your code should work:

```
oil_series.index = oil_series.index.get_level_values('date')

# Your code here.
mask = (oil_series.index.isin(dates)) & (oil_series <= 50)
```

Comment: It worked !! Thank you so much for taking the time. I really appreciate this.